# Test if a class is a subclass of another class in common lisp

Tags: lisp, class, common-lisp, clos, mop

How do I see if one CLOS class is a subclass of another CLOS class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the CLASS-NAME of a class.

A class has also a type of the same name.

SUBTYPEP tests if a type is a subtype of another type.

Answer (score 3):

[closer-mop](https://common-lisp.net/project/closer/closer-mop.html) provides a `subclassp` predicate

```
CL-USER> (c2mop:subclassp (find-class 'condition) (find-class 'error))
NIL
CL-USER> (c2mop:subclassp  (find-class 'error) (find-class 'condition))
T
```